# How can I use with-redefs to mock multiple calls to the same function?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, mocking, compojure

I would like to be able to mock `MyFunction` however I need the mock to return different values when `MyFunction` is called.

Is it possible to use `with-redefs` to return different values based on the call order of a function?

```
(testing "POST /foo/bar and return ok"
  (with-redefs [->Baz (fn [_]
                    (reify MyProtocol (MyFunction [_] [{:something 1}]))
                    (reify MyProtocol (MyFunction [_] [{:something 2}])))]

    (let [response (routes/foo {:request-method :post
                            :uri            "/foo/bar"
                            :query-params   {}
                            })]

      (is (= (:status response) 200)))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a mutable collection of the return values, then return/remove values from it on each call.

```
(defn foo [x] (inc x)) ;; example fn to be mocked
```

If you wanted to mock three calls to `foo` returning 1, 2, and 3 respectively:

```
(with-redefs [foo (let [results (atom [1 2 3])]
                    (fn [_] (ffirst (swap-vals! results rest))))]
  (prn (foo 0))
  (prn (foo 0))
  (prn (foo 0))
  ;; additional calls would return nil
  (prn (foo 0)))
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; nil
```

That uses `swap-vals!` to get the old/new values of the atom, but requires Clojure 1.9 or greater.

If you don't have `swap-vals!` you could do it (less atomically) like this:

```
(with-redefs [foo (let [results (atom [1 2 3])]
                    (fn [_]
                      (let [result (first @results)]
                        (swap! results rest)
                        result)))]
  ...)
```

Comment: I get `Unable to resolve symbol: swap-vals! in this context`

Comment: @Freid001 `swap-vals!` was introduced in Clojure 1.9, so you must be on a prior version. I updated with another example not using `swap-vals!`.

Answer (score 1):

We use Picomock for this, and to assert on the parameters for each call, and to assert on the number of calls. Recommended!